# Why didn't Horrorshow just kill Tolenka as soon as it could?

Tags: wild-cards

**Massive spoiler warning for the books: *Lowball* and *High Stakes*.**

The books *Lowball* and *High Stakes* feature a plotline that hinges on one crucial fact: Tolenka is using his willpower to stop Horrorshow from immediately manifesting onto the Earth. If Tolenka dies, then Horrorshow will be released immediately.

The whole plot of both books hinges on this crucial point because otherwise:

1. Baba Yaga would have had no motive to create her fight club (the reason why jokers were being kidnapped from New York in the first place). She could have just killed Tolenka at any time.
2. Even if Baba Yaga was saving Tolenka out of sentimentality, when Baba Yaga was in the hospital at Talas, she could have just sent one of her goons over to murder Tolenka the moment Horrorshow awoke. By that time she would have known that it was too late to save Tolenka.
3. One of the world's nuclear powers could have easily landed a tactical nuke on the Talas hospital at any time.

Presumably, Horrorshow knew that Tolenka was fighting it off and that it needed to kill him. And yet, over the course of a week Horrorshow was able to manifest a horde of monsters, mutate and enslave half of Talas's populace, and even conquer the minds of several potent aces like Lohengrin and the Midnight Angel. During this time, Horrorshow never once attempted to injure Tolenka, since Tolenka was still alive and unharmed when Detective Black found him a week later in the hospital. In fact, Horrorshow set up an army of creatures to defend Tolenka's body.

Why didn't Horrorshow just kill Tolenka the moment it could, like on day 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer I can think of is that Baba Yaga was wrong, but didn't know it. Tolenka's live body was absolutely required for Horrorshow to manifest on Earth. This actually makes sense, because one would expect that Tolenka's body and Wild Card power were acting as a conduit to bring in Horrorshow.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Boba Yoga *was* right. If Tolenka were to die before Horrorshow had fully, physically manifested into our reality, then it would remain on Earth, trapped in his body (still extremely dangerous, but perhaps much less powerful). In this scenario, Horrorshow would have been motivated to keep Tolenka alive until it had fully manifested, but Boba Yoga would still have been correct that killing Tolenka was a *very bad idea*.